# is it possible to use ssh in pod?

Tags: hadoop, ssh, kubernetes, centos, cluster-computing

I made hadoop image based on centos using dockerfile. There are 4 nodes. I want to configure cluster using ssh-copy-id. But an error has occurred.

```
ERROR: ssh: connect to host [ip] port 22: Connection refused
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This clearly points to unexposed port. Is your ssh server up?

Comment: It is said that status check is not possible in Pod. By default, 'systemctl' is not available. But I started ssh in Dockerfile. as shown in 'CMD ["/usr/sbin/ssh", "--foreground"]'

Comment: It's clearly said that container should consist of a single application. You are going to place 2 different apps to the single container (hadoop + ssh). It is not recommended due to container is not a virtual machine and some other reasons, e.g. signal handling, decoupling, scaling etc.

Comment: I have to configure hadoop clusters in kubernetes. Is there a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` follows a client-server architecture. So, the `openssh-server` has to be installed in the container. Now `ssh-copy-id` and other commands should run if the ip address is routable.

Comment: I installed openssh-server and openssh-clients on containers.  Ping is also good.  But not ssh from pod to pod. The same error occurs as above.

Comment: Did you check debug message while loging in with `-v` option. (`ssh -v root@IP`)

Comment: Not yet. I'll try that.